# jQuery click not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple html file with little bit of jQuery in it but click event is not triggered here:

I am not getting any error and neither the console.log statement that I expect to print when click event is triggered.
  Did I miss out on something?

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
      <title>My WebPage</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Day.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Night.css"/>
  </head>
    <body>
        <h1> My website </h1>
        <button>Day</button>
        <button>Night</button>
        <script src="jquery.js"/>

       <script>
           (function(){
            console.log('Inside func');
              $('button').click(function() {
              console.log('button was clicked');
              });
            })();
       </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script src="jquery.js"/>
```

should become:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

You can read more about self-closing script tags here: [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the JQuery CDN in the head section.

[Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/vivoso/1/edit?html,output)